# Logback exclude logger from root

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have a few packaged and I want to separate logging.

```
<property name="A" value="com.a"/>
<property name="B" value="com.b"/>
<property name="C" value="com.c"/>

<logger name="${A}" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_A"/>
</logger>

<logger name="${B}" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_B"/>
</logger>

<logger name="${C}" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_B"/> <!-- yes B -->
</logger>

<root level="DEBUG">      
    <-- used for other logs too ->
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ROOT_FILE"/>
</root>
```

So I have FILE_A FILE_B AND ROOT_FILE;
ROOT_FILE contains info that writes by root logger and by A B and C loggers.

How I can exclude FILE_A FILE_B info from ROOT_FILE ?

Or in another words how i can exclude log data (com.c  com.b  com.a) from root logger ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

set `additivity` flag for `com.a` and `com.b` loggers to false.

```
<logger name="${A}" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
     <appender-ref ref="FILE_A"/>
</logger>
```

now events logged in that logger won't be propagated to parent loggers (root logger in your case).

[documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help.